# What is the async/await version of a class which starts/stops a 'service' Task?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

In older C# we might come across code like this, which allows you to start/stop a Task (realistically a thread) which runs continuously like a background worker thread... probably servicing a queue or whatever:

```
class ServiceTask
{
    private Task task;
    private CancellationTokenSource cancellation = new CancellationTokenSource();
    public void Start()
    {
        task = Task.Run(() => TaskLoop(),cancellation.Token);
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        cancellation.Cancel();
        task.Wait();
    }

    private void TaskLoop()
    {
       while(!cancellation.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
       { ... }
    }
```

Apologies for the crude example but my query is, what would a modern async/await equivalent look like? Is it as simple as `await`-ing on the task instead of `Wait`-ing?

*(To clarify: this might look like an actual service in my example but my question is about this code pattern specifically... full real-life code is too large and complex to post all the details)*

Comment: Have a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.ihostedservice?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1

Comment: This doesn't start/stop anything, nor does it map to a thread. This *is* a "modern" example - `Task.Run()` was introduced along with `async/await`. The `Stop` method could be `async Stop(){ ...; await ...}` from the start. The biggest problem though is that it blocks a threadpool thread forever, to do sync work

Comment: And there are several examples for HostedService here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: Frankly, the wrapper class isn't needed.

Comment: A far better way to implement a worker would be to use eg ActionBlock<T>, which was also introduced in .NET 4.5, and have it process the messages posted to it asynchronously. By default, it processes 1 message at a time, but a higher DOP can be used. It already has an input buffer and can be configured to limit its size for throttling/backpressure scenarios

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I think you're second-guessing beyond the question, which _requires_ the Start/Stop API for some external code.

Comment: @SirRufo I was going to say this can't _be_ a service but I may misunderstand that interface, it doesn't force my module to be a Windows service right, but offers a way to do what I'm proposing in a more standard way? Not something I ever used before.

Comment: @Mr.Boy there's no `Start` here. This attempts to make a Task work like a thread. It's not one, and doesn't work that way. It's actually *better* to create a raw Thread than block a ThreadPool thread for a long time. That TaskPool is probably going to each an entire core too, even if it blocks periodically. Putting a thread to sleep is expensive, so blocking typically starts with a spinwait before putting the thread to sleep. On a high traffic system, this could result in constant spinwaiting

Comment: There are better ways to create service workers - eg a timer that runs a callback on a threadpool thread. Or, if that ThreadLoop was async, an `await Task.Delay()`. Given a concurrent collection with `async` methods (like System.Threading.Channels), one could implement pub/sub without blocking. DataFlow blocks implement both pub/sub and pipelining

Answer (score 2):

The Async/Await and Start/Stop might look similar, but they have different semantics.

The Task with async/await is intended to represent a task that finishes on it's own. The primary workflow is that it is started on creation and will finish on it's own. The cancellation mechanism is not the primary flow.

The Start/Stop has different semantics, in that it will never end on it's own. It will continue running until Stop is called. And while it can stop on it's own, the main flow is that it will run indenfinetely.

With the above said, I can conclude that both Task/async/await and start/stop semantics have their places in modern C# world. They both deal with different modes of operation. It is just that Tasks are more visible and more used, because their use-cases are more common.

Comment: This is an interesting point, that something that stops as _normal_ operation doesn't really map to a `Task` that well. So what does? Is it a case where simply running up a `Thread` is reasonable?